# Creating a Python package -- how to have the name of the package be imported directly?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I'm trying to create a Python package called "foo" that contains a bunch of functions, eventually to be published with PyPI.  I want it to work like this:

```
import foo
foo.func("parameter")
```

But I can't figure out how to just import foo and use its functions.  I have foo.py (which just has a bunch of functions) and __init__.py both in a folder called foo.  Other stuff (i.e, LICENSE, README.md, setup.py) is one level up.  In order to use the functions in foo.py, right now I need to type:

```
from foo import foo
foo.func("parameter")
```

Since when I try just

> import foo

and then to use a function, I get

```
AttributeError: module 'foo' has no attribute 'func'
```

This error makes sense, but I don't know how to fix it.  It doesn't seem right to do it the second way (from foo import foo?).  I feel dumb, but I've been stuck trying to get it to the first way all afternoon.  I keep trying to mess with __init__.py to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in your `__init__.py` something like

```
import foo

function_name = foo.function_name
```

Then, from other package you can do

```
from foo import function_name
```

Comment: or just `from .foo import *`